# Sublime text word_separator CamelCase

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

The sublime text `word_separator` is:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

I would also like case change in CamelCase to be considered change. Is there a setting/way to do this?

(Eg in FooBar ctrl+bck_space should delete only Bar).

Comment: Press alt instead of ctrl

Comment: Alt + Delete is not bound.

Answer (score 52):

In the event anyone is still looking at this...

In your default keybindings you'll find:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "word_ends", "forward": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": false, "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "word_ends", "forward": true, "extend": true} },

{ "keys": ["alt+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subword_ends", "forward": true} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+left"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subwords", "forward": false, "extend": true} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+right"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "subword_ends", "forward": true, "extend": true} },
```

Using alt+direction will move by "subwords" as opposed to "words", which takes into account camelCase. I prefer that over the default so I've copied the alt+direction set into my user keybindings and replaced the instances of alt with ctrl. Voila, ctrl+direction moves by camelCase as well as the defined word separators.

Also, I'm not sure if using the subwords setting will take into account underscores, I've always added _ to the word separators just to make sure.

Comment: As a sidenote: This setting seems to only work for Windows. On Mac the `Alt+Left` is system-default for "move by words" - I had to manually map `Super+Left` to "move by subwords" in the user defined key-bindings preferences

Comment: Subword separator is only `_` and change from upper to lower case. The name `foo1bar` has 1 subword, while `foo1Bar` has 2 subwords (foo1 + Bar), also `foo_bar` has 2 subwords (foo_ + bar)

Comment: @Philipp For me Alt+Left also works in OS X. _ (underscore) was not a default word separator so you'll have to add it yourself in Preferences.sublime-settings of user.

Answer (score 6):

Using alt works only for moving, not for delete, but I found something that works pretty well:

> Delete forward (alt+delete):

```
delete_subword.sublime-macro:
[
   {
      "command": "move",
      "args": {
         "by": "subwords",
         "extend": true,
         "forward": false
      }

   },
   {
      "args": null,
      "command": "left_delete"
   }
]
```

> Delete backward (alt+backspace)

```
delete_subword_forward.sublime-macro:
[
   {
      "command": "move",
      "args": {
         "by": "subwords",
         "extend": true,
         "forward": true
      }
   },
   {
      "args": null,
      "command": "right_delete"
   }
]
```

> Save it into your User directory. Now, you bind keys like this:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+backspace"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/delete_subword.sublime-macro"} },
{ "keys": ["alt+delete"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "Packages/User/delete_subword_forward.sublime-macro"} },
```

[Source](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3011)

Comment: This actually answers the question in reference to deleting by subword!

Answer (score 4):

I think this can only be done via a plugin, not simply by changing Sublime Text's settings.

This plugin looks promising:
https://github.com/jdc0589/CaseConversion

Answer (score 0):

`Alt + W` in vim mode works for me in sublime text 3 to traverse camelCase words

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adapt this movement and see sample code from this package which provides custom movement code:
https://github.com/robertcollier4/KeyboardNavigation
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/KeyboardNavigation

KeyboardNavigation - Keyboard movement and selection and deletion to custom delimeters. Navigate fast between contiguous boundaries. For SublimeText.